# Find pattern for new equation in number sequence

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

I saw this puzzle on this [address](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332160/find-the-missing-number-357-152181-456-202461-347-122172-945).

> $3+5+7=152181$
>
> $4+5+6=202461$
>
> $3+4+7=122172$
>
> $9+4+5=364518$
>
> $8+6+8=?$

I know that first $4$ digits are $4864$. How could I find last $2$ digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly, the last $2$ digits will be

> not $2$ digits, but $3$ digits! Which is $821$.

Because

> For $A + B + C$, the last $2$ (err.. $3$) digits will be the **reverse** of $A^2 \times (C-B)$.
>
>  $3+5+7$ will be $rev(3^2 \times (7-5)) = rev(18) = 81$.
>  $4+5+6$ will be $rev(4^2 \times (6-5)) = rev(16) = 61$.
>  $3+4+7$ will be $rev(3^2 \times (7-4)) = rev(27) = 72$.
>  $9+4+5$ will be $rev(9^2 \times (5-4)) = rev(81) = 18$.
>  $8+6+8$ will be $rev(8^2 \times (8-6)) = rev(128) = 821$.

Comment: I hope you can find a similar logic explaining the first four result digits that you have chosen to ignore in this answer; you have fitted a second degree polynomial + an arbitrary degree of freedom (the reversal) to four two-digit data points. This is always possible, given whichever numbers on the left side, so if this were the intended solution, the puzzle wouldn't be very well constructed at all.

Comment: Yeah, this may be a mess compared to the first four digits, which are plainly just ROT13(gur zhygvcyvpngvba bs n naq o gura n naq p). So let's see what could be the intended answer.